# Перекинуть файл из одной операционной системы в другую

Tags: файлы, dual-boot

У меня стоит Windows 10 и Ubuntu 18.04.03 LTS на ноутбуке. Хочу перекинуть папку с фотографиями с винды на убунту. Это возможно ? Задаю вопрос может быть не там, просто не знаю где его задать

Comment: Можно перекинуть файлы через почту, если объем небольшой. Можно перекинуть файлы через временное хранилище файлов в интернете типа файлообменника. Сейчас полно таких сервисов. Ну или тупо через USB-флешку.

Answer (score 3):

Винда сама по себе раздел убунту не увидит (хотя может и существуют утилиты). А из убунту можно открыть раздел винды и взять нужные файлы. Еще проще, если создан отдельный раздел с данными, который видит и винда и убунту.

Comment: Чтобы из венды увидеть раздел линукса, можно воспользоваться вот этим http://www.fs-driver.org

Comment: А можно пожалуйста узнать, как я могу из убунты найти то, что в винде? И создать этот раздел как? Я просто беру с какого нибудь диска пространства под этот раздел, нужно с ним как то манипулировать, с этим разделом?

Comment: @gbg "раздел линукса" — это настолько зыбкое понятие, что я бы вот так уверенно не стал утверждать. Например, IFS по вашей ссылке не читает ни ext4, ни XFS.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev, спасибо за уточнение.